# Why doesn't //* return the document node?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to understand the following example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<c> 
  <a> 
    <b att1="5">
        <c/>
    </b>  
    <d/> 
  </a>  
  <a att1="10"> 
    <d> 
      <c/> 
    </d>  
    <b/> 
  </a> 
</c>
```

Now I run the XPath query

```
//*[c]
```

which I take to mean "All nodes that have a child that is a c". However, this returns only the `<b>` and `<d>` nodes that have a `<c>` child without returning the Document node as I expected. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `//*` equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/*`. Notice that the document node referenced by `self::node()` in the previous XPath, so the outer most node selected by that XPath would be the child of the document node (due to `/*`), which is the root element `c`, which doesn't have direct child `c`, hence didn't get selected.

You want `/descendant-or-self::node()[c]` to include the document node, which is equivalent to `//.[c]`, see [the demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/dI_I7kHKY).

Comment: I would add that `"*"` means `child::*`, and `child::*` selects element nodes only. So even if you wrote `self::*`, it wouldn't select the document node, because the document node isn't an element.